# rworldmap color scale not continuous

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

I am using following example data and code to produce a map of world:

```
dF = read.table(text="
country, value
'France',  7
'United Kingdom',  64
'Italy',  68
'Sweden',  82
'Nepal',  85
'Japan',  86
'Germany',  86
'United States',  93
'China',  94
'Nigeria',  95"
, header=TRUE, sep=",")

library(rworldmap)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(dF,
                            joinCode = "NAME",
                            nameJoinColumn = "country",
                            verbose = TRUE)

library(RColorBrewer)
colourPalette <- brewer.pal(7,'RdYlGn')
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette)
```

However, the colors filled on map are not in a continuous scale. The United Kingdom is shown in almost the same color as France although their values are very different. Also China and United States are filled with different colors although their values are almost same. I think the colors are being filled as for categorical values and not on a continuous gradient scale. Changing the brewer.pal value from 7 to others does not help. How can I correct this? Thanks for your help.

---

**Edit**

Adding dput of `dF` which will help others to reproduce data frame

```
structure(list(country = c("France", "United Kingdom", "Italy", 
"Sweden", "Nepal", "Japan", "Germany", "United States", "China", 
"Nigeria"), value = c(7L, 64L, 68L, 82L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 93L, 
94L, 95L)), .Names = c("country", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Example not reproducible.

Comment: @Pascal - Its happening because while creating dataframe some extra whitespace is being added... which is not getting matched in `joinCountryData2Map` ..

Comment: White spaces removed from dF=  statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is because you are using the default catMethod for mapCountryData which is 'quantiles'. If you set catMethod to 'fixedWidth' I think you will get a result closer to what you want.

```
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette,catMethod='fixedWidth')
```

Or you can specify the category breaks with e.g. catMethod=c(0,20,40,60,80,100)

```
colourPalette <- brewer.pal(5,'RdYlGn')
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette,catMethod=c(0,20,40,60,80,100))
```

Then you can add a more detailed legend if you wish.

```
mapParams <- mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot="value", colourPalette=colourPalette, catMethod=c(0,20,40,60,80,100), addLegend=FALSE)

do.call( addMapLegend, c( mapParams
                          , legendLabels="all"
                          , legendWidth=0.5 ))
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, congratualations on producing such a good software. Regarding this problem, I was looking for your first solution that produces a continuous scale automatically on any data. If the term 'continuous' or 'gradient' is included (instead of 'fixedwidth'), it will become easy to understand. I want to use this red-yellow-green scheme on continuous data. Any other way I can make it more effective?

Comment: @rnso Thanks! You are right I could make it clearer, just need to find the time. There isn't a continuous option but you can increase `numCats` to get a similar effect like this. `mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette,catMethod='fixedWidth',numCats=100)`

Answer (score 2):

Reason behind the plotting was, next value after France is UK plus you have 10 countries and you are dividing them into 7 categories which made France and UK in same color category. By default mapCountryData takes 7 category for plotting...

**Following chart prepared by your code**
[image: Following chart prepared by your code]

Try to provide category exclusively. Try following...

```
colourPalette <- brewer.pal(nrow(dF),'RdYlGn')
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette,numCats=nrow(dF))
```

**Following chart prepared after introducing category exclusively**
[image: Following chart prepared after introducing category exclusively]

---

**Update**

Case where you want only lower values to be colored red (in this case france)

```
library(fields)
colourPalette = two.colors(n=max(dF$value)-min(dF$value)+1, start="red", middle='yellow', end="dark green", alpha=1.0)
colourPalette = colourPalette[dF$value - min(dF$value) + 1]
mapCountryData(sPDF,nameColumnToPlot="value",colourPalette=colourPalette, numCats=nrow(dF))
```

Output would be
[image]

Comment: I want to have colors plotted according to value itself and not according to category. I want continuous color gradient according to the 'value' parameter. Hence, France should be shown in red and all other countries should come in different shades of green.

Comment: Is it not possible to use continuous color gradient scale (and avoid categorial scale) as shown on this page: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html .

Comment: I thought you want to use rworldmap package... If you want to make maps with ggplot then you can use ggmap..

Comment: I had to edit above comment. But question remains the same that whether it is possible to have continuous color gradient scale in rworldmap?

Comment: Colors are continuous only problem is france is outlier which give illusion that colors are not continuous.. You only wanted France in red and other in green shade.. Which is the case I added..?

Comment: Thanks for your interest but I do not want to exclude any datapoints, including outliers. Continous scale is possible with other packages also, eg: library(latticeExtra); dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000), z = rnorm(1000, mean = 1)); maxz <- max(abs(dat$z)); levelplot(z ~ x * y, dat, at = seq(-maxz, maxz, length = 100), panel = panel.levelplot.points, par.settings = custom.theme.2())

Comment: I am not asking to drop ay points I was just just saying due to value of France so low continuous scale looks like this... Otherwise you can see another answer added by Andy..who also have mentioned to change category. That's all you have to do.. Plus last in my last update I created continuous scale on scale of value and put off which using only those for which value field exist..